# Delete user's profile

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my application I can delete a user's profile using an API. 
I don't understand why this code doesn't work.

```
deleteUser() {
      let ctrl = true;
      if (ctrl) {
        let formdata = new FormData();
        const identity = {
          MyAppName: {
            Username: this.props.cf, 
          }
        };
        console.log("identity: ", identity)
        formdata.append("Identity", JSON.stringify(identity));
        fetch(linktomyapi, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        },
          body: formdata
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseData => {
          console.log("responseData - ", responseData)
          Alert.alert("Eliminated.")
          global.utente =  Utente.clearUserLogged()
          Actions.homepage();
        })
        .catch(err => alert("err:" + err));
      }
    }
```

from Identity `console.log` I receive the right username that I passed.

While about the `responseData`:

```
responseData -  
{Error: {…}}
Error: {Code: "0000", shortMessage: "Generic Error"}
__proto__: Object
```

I have tried with CocoaRestClient the api and it works

Where is the problem in your Opinion??

Comment: Your API throws an error. Are you sure that it can accept the data as FormData that contains a stringified object? Since you usually have simple key/value pairs in FormData. That would be the first thing to check. Is what I send the same as what the API expects? What also looks weird to me is that you mention a REST client, but this is not a REST compatible request, since for a REST-compatible interface you would send a DELETE request instead of a POST to remove something.

Comment: @Shilly First, thanks for the reply. I tried to use the bee on cocoa and just enter the username to cancel.

Looking in the cocoa headers are: Content-type: multipart/form-data

Comment: What do the docs of your API say you should send? Have you looked at the error log of the API for more information than just 'generic error' ? Since we won't be able to find out the issue with only the current information. Only issue with your client code I could see is that this.props.cf is not the user name. But I expect that's the first thing you checked.

Comment: The doces in my APi said that I should sent like Header Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
No in my app the console.log give me only a generic error message.

Comment: Yes the this.props.cf is the parameter that I need to pass :(

Comment: But do you need to make a POST request? A GET request? What keys should be available in your form data for the API to work? What data types does the API expect? Have you checked all of that?

Comment: Yes a Post request. I have checked this

Comment: If everything you show here is correct according to the docs, you'll need to go look at the API server itself. Nothing you can do on the client or that we can say until you know what the generic error is.

Comment: @Shilly so in your opinion there aren't error in the code?

Comment: If you would have an error in your client code, you would not get a response from the API server, but an error on the client side. But you do get a response, and the response is an error. So I would expect that the API created that error because it cannot handle your request properly. Hence I asked if you are sure that what you send and how you send it, is what the API expects. We cannot check your API so you should figure out what that error means and then come back here once you know what the actual problem is.